# How can I add ios or android platform specific select field in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have installed `react-native-picker-select` library in `react-native 0.66` but I can not see select box model as I expected.

`packages.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4"
  },
```

**Actual Result**

```
 Render error
requireNativeComponent: "RNPicker" was not found in the UI Manager.
```

Fix of this issue or recommendation of another library is highly appreciated

Comment: This error caused by RNPicker native dependecy was not found in the current app build. Go through installation steps again and try to don't miss any step. You also need to re-install application after installing a native dependency (react-native run-android or run-ios). Also try cleaning build folder and try build again (`gradlew clean` for android, `Menu Bar → Product → Clean` for xcode).

Comment: Blocker: react-native app can not be opened on my xcode and after re-installing `react-native-picker-select`  and `react-native-picker-select": "3.0.1"` this error comes across ```Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker```

Comment: You're trying to install an old version of the library and seems like that version uses the Picker component in react native itself which is now deprecated and removed from react native. You need to install the recent version and @react-native-picker/picker library as the docs of the library states https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select#installing

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer based on @Ugur Eren answer
steps taken

- I uninstalled my app from ios in emulator

```
npm install @react-native-picker/picker --save
pod install
npx react-native run-ios
```

Then app is correcting correctly I can select item from list